# Matplotlib saving state between different uses of io.bytesIo

Tags: python, matplotlib, buffer

I have a function that returns the raw contents of a .png:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plotVoltage(dbc,imei,sMonth,sDay,sYear):
    ...
    plt.figure(1) 
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.plot(Xs,Ys,color='blue',linewidth=2)

    buf = None #DOES NOT SOLVE PROBLEM
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf.read()
```

And a flask function which returns the image as an HTTP response:

```
@app.route('/voltageOverTime', methods=['GET'])
def vot():
   ret = plotVoltage(some_parameters)) 
   resp = Response(response=ret,
                status=200,
                mimetype="image/png")
   return resp
```

Then finally somwhere I have a .html file where the image source is set to `/voltageOverTime` with some parameters when a button is clicked. The problem is, if I click the button multiple times with different parameters, the images "pile on top" of each other; I see each line plotted on top of one another. I think this is related to the memory buffer, e.g., each time I click the button it just adds to this buffer. How can I make this buffer completely flush?

Comment: Where do you create "plt"? The buffer is definitely not being reused with your code (the `= None` line is redundant anyways), but plt might.

Comment: Ugh, that library looks like they threw away good design in the name of "convenience". I guess that's to be expected when it's based on freaking MATLAB...

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen To be fair in this case the user is a) explicitly using the state machine (that is what the `import matplotlib.pyplot` is) and b) in explicitly reusing the same figure.  This is very useful if you are using mpl interactively.

Comment: also, `plt.clf()` will solve the problem and be marginally faster (as in probably not detectable).

Comment: @tcaswell: I'm not really surprised people would make that mistake when all the tutorials I could find only show this way as well. How does one even create a new figure object to use instead of storing state on the module level?

Comment: A vast majority of the use of mpl _is_ at a repl, hence the emphasis on the state-machine interface.  Making it easier to use with out pyplot (and document how to do it!) are on the radar for the near future.  I just take a bit of issue with your judgments about the library design based on pyplot ;)

Comment: and see my answer for how to do this without pyplot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.close) indicates that calling `plt.close()` after you're done with a plot should free it from memory and clean it up.

In a properly designed Python library you would create a new object for each figure instead of holding state directly in the module, so that confusion like this wouldn't happen.

Comment: Um, yes, this was quite confusing! I've never imagined that state would be preserved like that!!

Comment: It's not usually a problem for simple scripts that just execute and then end, but web apps tend to run for a long while at a time and badly designed libraries like this make it really easy to accidentally accumulate state.

Answer (score 4):

To do this with out using the `pyplot` interface:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.figure
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def demo():
    fig = Figure(figsize=(10,  10), dpi=100)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    ax = fig.add_axes([.1, .1, .8, .8])

    ax.plot(range(15))
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')

    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf.read()
```

Comment: *This* is more like what I'm talking about (check it out @Tommy). Now put it in the docs in the "how to use in an application" section. What's the canvas for though? It's created but seemingly not used. Also: `fromat`

Comment: The canvas is the thing that knows how to make the pixels colored.  If the `FigureCanvas` was imported from `matplotlib.backends.backend_svg` the output would have been an svg file. And see http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/index.html.  Those examples are all for gui embedding, but it's the same idea.